# (Excel) Giving the smallest value between 2 values

Tags: excel, vba

[Excel data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPzHd.png)

I am new to here. If I have any mistake in making new post, Please tell me and I am ready to correct my mistake.

For above pic, I want to extract the 2 smallest values in column D respectively between row 77 and row 84, and between row 84 and 97. The resulting values are shown in P77 and P84 respectively.

How should I write the excel formula for it? Or it needs VBA to code it?

Thanks a lot for your sincere help!

(Update)
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke1nG.png)
above pic is another capture of my data set which filtered the day with "Bullish breaking candle/bearish breaking candle" only.

Thanks

Comment: Smallest value of which column.. 'min(A1:S10)' is the you have use

Comment: Sorry, mates. I forgot to mention that the data set have 12457 rows of data.It just a part of it. Here is another capture of my data set. (btw, can anyone tell me how i can post the table here instead of capturing it?)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of functions/ways to calculate Minimum in addition to the `MIN` function and it is **worth** being familiar with them as you will require different ones according to your data.

So quick rundown of some of the main offerings:

**SMALL function:**

I would consider also the more versatile [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07) function

`=SMALL(D77:D84,1)` in cell P77

`=SMALL(D84:D97,1)` in cell P84

You put the array (the range of cells to compare) then the k-th smallest item in that range that you want to retrieve e.g. put 1 to get the smallest, as above, comparable to MIN function, or 2 to get the second smallest etc.

Official blurb below:

> Description
>
> Returns the k-th smallest value in a data set. Use this function to
>   return values with a particular relative standing in a data set.
>
> Syntax
>
> SMALL(array, k)
>
> The SMALL function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Array    Required. An array or range of numerical data for which you
>   want to determine the k-th smallest value.
>
> K    Required. The position (from the smallest) in the array or range
>   of data to return.

**AGGREGATE Function:**

Consider the even more versatile [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) function which can cope with hidden rows in the range, errors etc. You can specify a host of additional requirements whilst still getting the minimum value

General syntax for first form:

> AGGREGATE(function_num, options, ref1, [ref2], …)

Function 5 is Minimum.  Options are viewable at link I gave but 7 is ignore errors and hidden rows. So, you could use:

```
=AGGREGATE(5,7,D77:D84)
```

The AGGREGATE option above is the only version that will still return the minimum correctly if there is an error in the range D77:D84 e.g. a DIV/0 error.

**SUBTOTAL Function:**

Similar to the AGGREGATE function is the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function.

You can use `SUBTOTAL(5, D77:D84)` where 5 specifies you want the minimum for the range. This will not ignore errors. SUBTOTAL(105,D77:D84) will ignore hidden rows though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the formula '=Min(D77:D84)' in cell P77
and '=Min(D84:D97)' in cell P84